# Apply zero tax to Australian orders over $1000 in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

Due to the new Australian gst rules I need to be able to charge standard gst on sales to Australian customers with a value less than $1000, and zero rated gst on sales above $1000 (as these are handled by AU customs).

I would like to use [Set different Tax rates conditionally based on cart item prices in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950932/set-different-tax-rates-conditionally-based-on-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce/44964389#44964389) answer code that can be adapted to my needs, targeting orders with an Australian shipping address.

If anyone has any idea how I can do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Using a similar code to the linked answer, you can try the following that will target Australian customers which cart subtotal is up to **`$1000`**:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate', 10, 1 );
function apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Targeting australia billing country only
    if ( WC()->customer->get_billing_country() !== 'AU' )
        return;

    $defined_amount = 1000;
    $subtotal = 0;

    // Loop through cart items (1st loop - get cart subtotal)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];
    }

    // Targeting cart subtotal up to the "defined amount"
    if ( $subtotal < $defined_amount )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items (2nd loop - Change tax rate)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'zero-rate' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec, thank you so much for looking at this for me :) Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. When a cart has an AU billing address the tax changes to 15% (NZ GST). I'm assuming this is due to me having a couple of zero rated tax classes so perhaps it's taking on the default instead? The AU zero rated tax class is listed as <tr class="tips" data-tip="Tax rate ID: 4" data-id="4">, how would I call this specific class instead of 'set_tax_class( 'zero-rate' );'? I've tried a couple of things but have so far failed horribly haha! Thanks for your help!