# WooCommerce: Change tax rate when specific products are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

I am trying to change the tax rate in WooCommerce when specific product IDs are in the cart. I found *[Set 'Zero Tax' for subtotal under $110 - Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553855/set-zero-tax-for-subtotal-under-110-woocommerce/56572382#56572382)* answer code and it works. I just can't figure out how to modify it to check for product ID's in the cart.

Comment: Some feed back on the answer below will be really appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

The following will set "Zero Tax" for specific products if subtotal is under $110 in:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate', 10, 1 );
function apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $targeted_product_ids = array(37, 53); // Here define your specific products
    $defined_amount = 110;
    $subtotal = 0;

    // Loop through cart items (1st loop - get cart subtotal)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];
    }

    // Targeting cart subtotal up to the "defined amount"
    if ( $subtotal > $defined_amount )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items (2nd loop - Change tax rate)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'zero-rate' );
        }
    }
}
```

Or the following will set "Zero Tax" when any specific product is in cart and when subtotal is under $110:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate', 10, 1 );
function apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    $targeted_product_ids = array(37, 53); // Here define your specific products
    $defined_amount = 110;
    $subtotal = 0;
    $found = false;

    // Loop through cart items (1st loop - get cart subtotal)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];

        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $found = true;
        }
    }

    // Targeting cart subtotal up to the "defined amount"
    if ( ! ( $subtotal <= $defined_amount && $found ) )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items (2nd loop - Change tax rate)
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'zero-rate' );
    }
}
```