# Set zero taxes when total cart value before taxes is lower than a set amount - woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, checkout, subtotal, tax

I have been reading this article [Set 'Zero Tax' for subtotal under $110 - Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56553855/set-zero-tax-for-subtotal-under-110-woocommerce/56572382#56572382) as reference to assign ‘zero’ taxes when total cart value < 800 (otherwise it applies another tax class). In my case I applied it only to parcels shipped to US. Upon testing the code, it seems that the $subtotal loop returns 0 instead of the real total cart value before taxes ($400). Any idea as to why? Below is my edited code. Thanks!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate', 10, 1 );

    function apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

     if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() !== 'US' )
        return;

         $defined_amount = 800;
         $subtotal = 0;

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];
        }

        if ( $subtotal < $defined_amount )
        return;

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'zero' );
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't immediately see an error in your code. Have you debugged to know the subtotal value effectively? are you perhaps using other custom code or plugin that could be of influence?

Comment: @7uc1f3r - Thanks for checking my code. The way I tested it is by setting $defined_amount = 0 and $subtotal = 10. Then I set the following condition if ($subtotal = $defined_amount) into the code, which returned 'zero' tax class. So I assumed that the loop has overridden the initial $subtotal value of 10 with zero. When I set condition if ($subtotal > $defined_amount), the 'other' tax class is selected.

Comment: If you tested this by setting `$subtotal` to 10, then the 10 can never be overwritten by 0, even if the loop is executed. Because in the loop the line_total is added to the  `$subtotal` so it can only be 10 or more than 10. 
As I mentioned, [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61740111/how-to-debug-in-woocommerce-3) seems to be the only correct way to come to a solution

Comment: This is very helpful indeed. Thank you for your suggestion. Manu

Answer (score 0):

After debugging, the below edited code works for me:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate', 10, 1 );

function apply_conditionally_zero_tax_rate( $cart ) {
     

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;
              

    if ( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country() !== 'US' )
        return;
  

    $defined_amount = 800;
    $subtotal = 0;

  
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $subtotal += $cart_item['line_total'];
    }
       

    if ( $subtotal > $defined_amount ){

      foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'zero' );
      }
    }  
}
```