# Change WooCommerce cart item tax rate based on the item discounted price

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, price, discount

I want to calculate the tax based on the item price after discount.

I have two tax rates: 5% GST and 12% GST.

For products with price after discount that is less than 1000, I want to apply a tax rate of 5%.

For products with price after discount that is more than up to 1000, I want to apply a tax rate of 12%.

I have used the following code, but it doesn't alter the tax rate after applying discounts.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function change_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // get product price
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        // Set conditionaly based on price the tax class
        if ( $price <= 999 )
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( '5% GST' ); // below 999
        if ( $price > 999 )
            $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( '12% GST' ); // Above 999
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite unsure how the tax rate would change based on the price of an item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first **to get the tax rate slugs**, but not the tax name as you are actually using "5% GST" and "12% GST" which are tax names.

The following function will display only for "administrator" user role, the correct tax rate(s) slug(s) to be used:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'display_all_tax_rates_slugs_in_the_footer', 10);
function display_all_tax_rates_slugs_in_the_footer() {
    // Displayed only to administrator user role
    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) 
        return;

    echo '<div style="max-width:450px;">
    
    <table style="border:solid 1px #000;">
        <thead><tr><th colspan="2"><h4>Tax rates</h4></th><tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Slug <i><small>(to be used)</small></i></th><tr>';

    foreach ( wc_get_product_tax_class_options() as $tax_rate_slug => $tax_rate_label_name ) {
        echo "<tr><td>'{$tax_rate_label_name}'</td><td><code>'{$tax_rate_slug}'</code></td></tr>"; 
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></div>';
}
```

something like:

[image]

Once you get the correct tax rate slug(s) remove this function.

---

The following code uses the discounted item subtotal to get the item discounted price, to set different tax rate based on this item discounted price:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_cart_items_prices', 10, 1 );
function change_cart_items_prices( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        // Get discounted item price excluding taxes
        $price = $item['line_total'] / $item['quantity'];

        // Set conditionally item tax class based on discounted item price
        $item['data']->set_tax_class( $price < 1000 ? 'reduced-rate' : '' ); 
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Related: [Set different Tax rates conditionally based on cart item prices in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44950932/set-different-tax-rates-conditionally-based-on-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce/44964389#44964389)